# Azure Repository: unlimited merge conflicts in pull request

Tags: azure, azure-devops, repository, azure-repos

It seems like I am facing a bug within my Azure Devops repository.
Within my pull request I have merge conflicts.
Every time I solve these and resolve the matching comment, a new merge conflict appears.

Here you can see I resolved all the issues:
[image]

Next when I return to the overview page a new merge conflict is shown:
[image]

When I solve this and go back to the overview page a new merge conflict is shown.

This keeps on happening.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a bug in Azure DevOps but Way of Working.

Every conflict when manually resolved from the AzureDevops `Conflicts` tab, will have a comment created. Before completing the PR approval, the peer reviewer needs to resolve this comment related to the conflict resolution.

Comment: Hi, the problem is that every time all the conflicts are accepted and the comments resolved new conflicts pop up. I turned off that I need a peer reviewer.

Comment: I would check if there is already another app or a person making changes on that that file in the `main` branch